Is there a lower bound of $| \pi/4 - a/b|$ dependent only on b?
I was wondering if there exists a lower bound for $| \pi/4 -a/b|$, where $b$ is an integer and $a$ is chosen such that $a/b$ is the best approximation to $\pi/4$, which only depends on $b$. I am not too familiar with the theory of Diophantine approximation since it is not taught at my university, so I apologize if this question is either fruitless or trivial.
For illustration, if we denote the convergents of $\pi/4$ to be $p_n/b_n$ and the integers in the continued fraction expansion of $\pi/4$ to be $c_n$ then the following inequality given in MathWorld is precisely what I need
$$
\frac1{(c_{n+1}+2)q^2_n} < \left| \frac{\pi}4 - \frac a b \right|
$$
for $q_n < b < q_{n+1}$. However, a problem arises when I try to estimate $c_{n+1}$. For what I have been able to find, there is little known about the sequence $c_n$, except for the fact that it is unbounded. Empirically, the inequality $b>c_{n+1}+2$ holds for large enough $b$, yielding the lower bound $1/b^3$, however proving this is beyond me.
Thanks.

Presumably, you mean $a$ is an integer, also.

It seems unlikely you can get a lower bound. There are, for example, for algebraic numbers lower bounds that work of the form $\frac1{p(b)}$ for some polynomial $p,$ but you need a lot more information about transcendental numbers.

This is roughly related to the irrationality measure of $\frac\pi4,$ which I bet is unknown. If course, we could just define $f(b)=\inf_a |\pi/4-a/b| ,$ so such an $f$ exists, but presumably you want $f$ to be decreasing and represented by some usual sort of function. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html

According to that link, the irrationality measure of $\pi,$ hence $\pi/4,$ is less than 8, so $f(b)=\frac1{Cb^8}$ works, for some constant $C.$ What that constant is I can't say, but it works all but finitely often with $C=1.$

I see that irrationality measure was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!
